# MSB aligned addition

Tags: c++, math, recursion, addition, constexpr

I'm looking for a way (preferably recursive) to add two integers with their msb aligned.

For example: 125 + 25 = 375.

I tried to reverse the digits to effectively align them but the carrying would be all wrong. ie. 526 (625) + 05 (50) = 531.

Comment: As an initial matter, how do you plan to represent `0600` (complete with the leading zero)?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik In my code, I calculate these numbers with a certain value and the leading zeros are known ie. some_constant * x

Comment: Find power of 10 less than or equal to each number, multiply the lesser one with division of the two powers of ten and then add with the bigger one.

Comment: And I think 375 instead of 275

Comment: @GurwinderSingh You're right this kind of addition challenges the basic math part of me

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I change my mind, it turns out I don't need to have a case for leading zeros

Comment: So im effect you want to add 125 and 250, though why you would want this kind of operation is a mystery. There is no such thing as "msb digit"; B in MSB stands for "bit', which is a binary digit, so "msb digit" would be "most significant binary digit digit", which is nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Calculate number of digits of both numbers using a while / 10 loop

2) Get the difference

3) Multiply smallest number by 10 ^ difference

4) Add them together

Comment: I just checked this with some code and this worked perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will need to include math.h for this. Assuming m and n are natural numbers, the below works by multiplying the smaller number by 10 (if needed) until it has the same number of digits as the larger, then adding.

```
int funkyAdd (int m, int n)
{
    if ((m<=0)||(n<=0)){return -1;}
    int smaller=std::min(m,n);
    int larger=std::max(m,n);
    while (floor(log10(smaller))<floor(log10(larger))){smaller*=10;};
    return (smaller+larger);
}
```